# MySQL separation by duplication

Tags: mysql, duplicates

consider the following:
3 tables:
Users, Businesses and Addresses.

The rows of both Users and Businesses have address_id fields that match rows in Addresses.
due to a bug (related to default values) I have a situation where for some addresses I have both a user and a business with the same addresss id.

I want to split it up so that it at the beginning I have

```
Users.id , Users.address_id  
1        , 1  
2        , 2  
3        , 3
```

and

```
Businesses.id , Businesses.address_id  
1             , 4  
2             , 3  
3             , 2  
4             , 5
```

and addresses has 5 rows with id=1 to 5 and some other info columns (city country etc).

I would like that businesses 2 and 3 that currently point to addresses (3 and 2) that are also used by users (3 and 2 respectively) would point to two new rows in addresses what will be copies of the original rows.

i.e.
add rows 6 and 7 to addresses which will be copies of row 3 and 2 respectively.
and set Businesses.address_id accordingly
(i.e.

updated Businesses should look like this:

```
Businesses.id, Businesses.address_id  
1            , 4  
2            , 6  
3            , 7  
4            , 5
```

so that every row in addresses will be used only by one of the two other tables, while data sematics remain the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no complete table structures makes this impossible to completely write so here's some psudo code.

1) Select records from address inner join business inner join users on the address ID.  this gets us those addresses which are currently shared.

2) insert into address the above records via a insert into table from (Select perhaps?)

3) lastly update business address ID set = max(addressID) where address fields = address fields from currrent allocation. (since we know there will be duplicated addresses) max will be the newer one.

Comment: I am afraid that max might be problematic if I have addresses that are not unique. (can be tested of course). I am thinking of temporarily adding a column with the original_address_id and populate appropriately  in phase 1 you mention above and then use it in phase 3 to update.

Comment: Step 2 will be inserting new records, therefore the MAX Should be the most recent address created. if you have duplicate address in address already then your right, I didn't understand the original problem.  but there is likely a way to find those addresses belonging to business which do not belong to users and instead of inserting / using max to use that ID instead.  So can 2 business share the same address?

Comment: I ended up using steps 1 and 2 but adding a temporary column for the old ID. This allowed me to safely modify the lines pointing to old rows without using max. thanks for the help.